# Failed to load image using glide

Tags: java, android, api, imageview, android-glide

In my application, I was trying to get the thumbnail of a book from google play books API and display it in an image view but somehow what I did is not working.

```
Glide.with(holder.thumb.getContext())
                    .load(curThumb)
                    .into(holder.thumb);
```

when I used the above method with a local image it worked also thumbnail URL is correct

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Make sure your image url starts with https not with http.

Comment: Thanks brother it worked, google api returns HTTP URL , had to change that to https. @HritikGupta

Comment: Anytime bother, Once this issue took my whole day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Glide v4.0.0-RC1 use RequestOptions to add the placeholder, error image and other options make sure URL(image_url) starts with https, not with HTTP

```
   RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                        .error(R.drawable.your_error_image);
```

RequestOptions to add placeholder, error image and to customize image

```
 Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```